# Adding column on specific row location

Tags: mysql

Its just a quick question :

I have user table and it has fields name, address and books_bought. books_bought is foreign key and its value is some PK from other table. Now after 1st insert, I will fill out all of this fields , but after second INSERT I want only to add a additional books_bought, so that am creating array of books_bought values?

Comment: Bad relational design. Should have `user table`, `books table` and a `sales table`. Sales shows user and book association as a "books bought"

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it the wrong way around - this is a [one-to-many](http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1tox/) relationship i.e. many books bought to one user. You need to have the foreign key on the *many* side of the relationship, so instead of having a foreign key to books_bought on the users table, add a foreign key to users on the books_bought table.

If you have a books table and a users table, then this is a [many-to-many](http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_xtox/) relationship and you will need a link table to go between them to hold the foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have more than one book in the books_bought cell  because it will violate the atomicity constraint fo the database tables. You have to have a separate entry for each book_bought. This would cause a lot of redundant information as name, address would be repeated for each book bought by a specific person.

To solve this, you have to split the table into something like this:
R1(primary_key , name , address)  and R2(foreign_key , books_bought)
Here foreign_key refers to primary_key of R1

Comment: Am thinking of adding a Sales table that has book id and user id fields, so every new purchase will be recorded there, and when I need info on what book user bought I will look there. Is this better design?

Comment: Yes that is a better design. So basically you'll now have three tables. Table1(userid, bookid) , Table2 (userid,name,address) and Table 3 which you mentioned in your question is referred to by books_bought. I hope you got it. I am not really good at explaining things. :P